# High CPU usage after long running

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, memory-leaks, cpu-usage

I have an issue with my application hope somebody can give me suggestions how to fix it.

I have multithread application. It tuns 10-20 threads and in each thread I execute some complicated tasks.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(ProcessThread);
thread.Start();

private void ProcessThread()
{
    while(IsRunning)
    {
        // do some very complex operations: grab HTTP pages. Save to files. Read from files. Run another threads etc.
    }
}
```

At the beginning app uses about 10% CPU and 140Mb memory. But after 1000 executes CPU usage is 25%-30% and memory is 1200Mb. I know that probably I have a memory leak in my code, I will try to fix it. But what happened with CPU? Why it grows? Each execution does the same operations as in the beginning and later (for example open web page, grab some info and save it to the file).

I think that the issue can be with GC. More memory app take, more CPU need to clean the memory?

The other question, could you please advise a good tool how to measure what take CPU in my app?

And maybe you can recommend a good tool to analyze memory and check where it leaks? I tried JetBrains dotMemory but didn't understand much. Maybe you can help me.
Here is the stat: 
http://prntscr.com/dev067
http://prntscr.com/dev7a2
As I see I don't have really too much unmanaged memory. But at the same time I see problems with strings, but can't understand what's wrong as GC must clean it?

Appreciate any suggestions and recommendations what I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are wrapping native types, I doubt you have a memory leak. The memory usage is most likely due to the way the GC works.

The GC will not collect all dead items in a cycle. It will use *generations*. That means it will collect older objects only if it needs the space. So the memory usage will increase until the first collection. Then, only a fraction of the items is collected, which will lower memory usage somewhat, but not completely. And the GC will also not necessarily return freed memory to the OS.

In higher editions of Visual Studio you'll find a memory profiler.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what are "some complicated tasks".
And this especially worries me:

```
// do some very complex operations: grab HTTP pages. Save to files. Read from files. Run another threads etc.
```

Well, if you are indeed starting new threads from your process thread, then it totally makes sense for CPU usage to raise. From performance perspective creation of new threads is costly, and that is a reason why we use thread pools(recycling threads).

The same goes for memory usage. More threads = more memory required for each thread (each thread has it's own stack requiring additional memory)...

Also, I don't believe that GC is a culprit here.

There is a lot of questions that need te be answered before I can help you find a cause of such a behavior, and before we can blame GC :):
1)Do you start all, let's say, 20 threads at the start of your program?
2)Do you create new threads from already running ones?
3)What is termination condition for those threads? Do they actually terminate?

I would recommend using dotTrace for determining CPU usage.
Unfortunately, I haven't used any tool for profiling memory usage so I cannot recommend any.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your screenshot and from that I see you have many objects which are surviving generation 0 collection so they are being escalated to generation 1 and then to generation 2. This could be a sign of a memory leak but not necessarily. Without seeing your code it is hard to say. All I can tell is that you are keeping your objects for a very long time. This may be needed but again I cannot tell without seeing the code.

**A bit about GC**

When the GC wakes up to cleanup, it analyzes the managed heap to see which objects are not rooted and marks them all ready for collection. This is called the **mark** phase. Then it starts deallocating the memory. This is called the **sweep** phase. If it cannot clean anything up, those objects go to generation 1. Sometime later the GC wakes up again and repeats the above but this time, since there are items in generation 1, if they cannot be collected they will go to generation 2. This could be a bad sign. Do the objects really need to be around for that long?

**So what can you do?**

You say the GC must clean stuff. Well yes the GC will clean things but only if you are not referencing them. If an object is rooted then GC will not be able to clean it.

**Write Code with GC in mind**

To start with the investigation, you need to investigate your code and make sure your code is written with GC in mind. Go through your code and make a list of all the objects you are using. If any object is of a class which implements IDisposable then wrap them in a using statement:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    // work here depends on font1
}
```

If you need `font1` in one of your classes as a class level variable, then you have to make the descision when to call `Dispose` on it: At the very least this class should implement IDisposable and call dispose on `font1`. Users of this class (any code which calls new on this class) should either use this class with the `using` statement or call `Dispose' on it.

Do not keep objects longer than you need them.

**Still need more investigation?**

Once you have investigated your code and ensured your code is friendlier to the GC and you still have issues then investigate using a tool. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/42721/best-practices-no-detecting-net-application-memo) is a good article to help you with this part.

Some people have the misconception that calling `GC.Collect()` will solve the memory leak issue. This is not true at all. Forcing a garbage collection will still follow the same rules and if objects are rooted, you can call `GC.Collect()` indefinitely, the objects will still not be cleaned up.

Here is a sample application which will show this:

```
public class Writer : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Write(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
} 

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Writer writer = new Writer();
        writer.Write("1");
        writer.Dispose();

        // writer will still be around because I am referencing it (rooted)
        writer.Write("2");

        GC.Collect();

        // calling GC.Collect() has no impact since writer is still rooted
        writer.Write("3");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only comment on why you have a CPU issue and not GC.

1. I suggest you verify that you are creating only the number threads you expect. If you happen to have threads launching threads, it's easy to slip up.
2. As mentioned in another comment, thread creation and destruction is costly. If you are creating and destroying threads all the time, this will have a notable impact upon your performance.
3. I suspect the cause of your slowdown is memory thrashing, meaning the amount of memory used by each thread is large enough, and/or the total amount used by all threads is large enough to cause memory pages to be swapped in and out all the time. In certain situations, the processor can spend more time swapping memory to and from disk than it spends executing the thread.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Use a thread pool. This minimizes the time you need for thread creation and destruction. This will also bound the number of threads you are using.
2. Make sure each thread executes a reasonable amount of time before it is swapped out -- i.e. you don't have the threads context thrashing.
3. Make sure the amount of memory each thread is using is not much larger than you expect to prevent memory thrashing.
4. If you have to use a large amount of memory for each thread, make sure your pattern of usage is such that there isn't a lot of memory paging.

Answer (score 0):

Run you application with ["Start collecting allocations data immediately" enabled](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/2016.2/Configuring_Profiling_Process.html), get snapshot after a while and look [at memory traffic view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/2016.2/Analyzing_Traffic.html).
To understand what occupies a memory open ["All objects" grouped by type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/2016.2/Analyzing_an_Object_Set.html) and look what types take the most amount of memory.

For performance profiling I could recommend JetBrains dotTrace (timeline mode, for your case).